# Java[Gson] - How to assign the correct type automatically to Json

Tags: java, gson

I'm trying to build json using Gson dynamically as following ,
loop through existing fields and take the name and value and build json based on it,

so for an input:

```
a="AString"
B=true
C=null
D=[1,2,3] 
E={"a":"b"}
```

will get valid json as:

```
{
"a":"AString",
"b": true,
"c": null,
"d":[1,2,3],
"e":{"a":"b"}
}
```

code:

```
JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
Field OutPortList[] = BBClass.class.getDeclaredFields();  


for(Field x : OutPortList)
{

jsonObject.addProperty(  x.getName() ,  x.get(this));

}
```

Getting error :

```
jsonObject.addProperty(  String , String ) is not applicable
```

also tried casting :

```
jsonObject.addProperty(  x.getName() , x.getType().cast(x.get(this)) );
```

Not sure but i guess it relate to type ,
as i try with x.get(this).toString() and its work but this will cast everything to string type.
I'm not sure what would be the correct way to handle the type automatically without casting it each time to the correct type.

Comment: Why are you iterating fields rather than letting Gson serialize the whole thing itself?

Comment: not clear what are you trying to do.
take BBClass with these fields and? make it json?

Comment: The BBClass is actually an external interface which I'm using reflect to get the existing field/s , each time this run it can get different field/s,  I don't have any way to know in advance what I get , I only i need to build up json from it .

Comment: I am not sure I understand, every time you get inputs it will be an implementation of  BBClass?

Comment: The set of possible described in the beginning of the post , 
The only way I can access the input is by reflect and hence the use of Field .
And it require to build the json by Filed.Name and Field.Value

Comment: is "this" an instance of BBClass?
Do you know you can move the class to JSON with no need to do it yourself?

Comment: x.get(this) is relate to instance of BBClass , note BBClass has also method but i need to refer only to fields (getDeclaredFields) ,I didnt know how can I move this class to Json but it sound like great solution would appreciate for any guidance

Comment: someone has already given you an example of how you should do...

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to squeeze a java.lang.Object into a JsonElement (the add method) or a String (the addProperty method). The type of the field could be anything, including types that have no direct counterpart in json.

The easiest way would be to rely on the marshalling gson provides.

```
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        
        gson.toJson( this );
```

which yields a json formatted string.

If for some reason you still want to iterate the fields manually, you could still use gsons type marshalling for building the properties. Like this:

```
        JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
        Field[] OutPortList = Test.class.getDeclaredFields();
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        for(Field x : OutPortList)
        {
            jsonObject.add( x.getName(), gson.toJsonTree( x.get(this) ) );
        }
```

Note, that you should consider sticking to Java naming conventions by using lowerCamelCase on variable names.

Comment: Thanks gl1tor , not sure i understand the first solution "this" is the current field in itteretion runs on Field ,can u please explain more about it ? is there an option take all existing Test.class.getDeclaredFields() and convert them all to Json ?

Comment: this is bb class instence

Comment: gson.toStringTree( x,get(this)) - seems working  for integer ,string and float , but for json object as {"test":1} it  adding slashes as "{\"test\": 1} , i tried toString() but didnt work

Comment: Yes, the first solution serializes `this`, which is in context of your code snippet the same object you're retrieving the field values from (`x.get(this)`). Behind the scenes gson also uses the Reflection API for this, just more sophisticated. For instance it handles the conversion to JsonElements for the "native" json type (like Boolean, String,...), but also handles custom types, like your class. For details see [here](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide). If you can, you should let gson do the serialization.

Comment: with current situation I prefer iterate on Field , it working good for all types except when type is jsonobject and it escaping the double quote as "{\"test\": 1} , what is the reason an how i can avoid it (and not clean it after)?

Comment: A `JsonObject` typed field should get serialized just fine, GSON handles the case where you pass in one of the JsonElements. I'd expect escaped double quotes in the output if the field in question is indeed `String` typed and contains a json formatted object. It's hard to tell without actually knowing the actual code.

Comment: yes,the field coming as java.String ,how should I handle that so I be able to add it to the json object properly?

Comment: You'd have to handle that case explicitly in your loop, i.e. test explicitly for the field in question then deserialize the string field and add the result it to the `jsonObject` to skip the marshalling. However, in most of the cases this is not what you want, you won't be able to deserialize the json into the same structure again. Also be aware that this is going to fail for String typed fields that don't contain json text.